# wlan0 to eth0 bridge works but MAC address gets mixed up

Tags: bridge, hostapd

I have an access point (`hostapd`) running on `wlan0`.  `wlan0` and `eth0` are bridged and `eth0` is hooked up to a router. `br0` is configured for DHCP and receives an address that is reserved on the router.

Let the box with the access point be called the access point box.

Occasionally, the router will show that the access point box has a MAC address of the `wlan0` device instead of the MAC of `eth0` like it should.

Any devices connected to the access point will show their respective MAC addresses on the router's arp cache.

The router has bridge firewall rules that enforce that all packets from the DHCP reserved IP address of the access point box must come from the MAC address of `eth0` so the box looses network connectivity when the MAC changes from `eth0` to `wlan0`. When the box looses connectivity, all associated clients on the access point are still able to use the Internet.

I was able to circumvent the router's bridge rules by using the following `ebtables` commands on the box that has `wlan0`.

```
ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -s $WLAN_MAC -j dnat --to-destination $LAN_MAC
ebtables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s $WLAN_MAC -j snat --to-source $LAN_MAC

ebtables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 --logical-in br0 -s $WLAN_MAC -j dnat --to-destination $LAN_MAC
ebtables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 --logical-out br0 -s $WLAN_MAC -j snat --to-source $LAN_MAC
```

Although the access point box never looses Internet connectivity, the router's arp cache still mixes up the MAC addresses. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

EDIT
I was able to clumsily solve this problem by setting the MAC address of `wlan0` to the same MAC as `eth0`. I do not like this solution and I want to make it work without changing the MAC of `wlan0` directly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I had to use arptables to mangle the packets that contained wlan0 mac to the eth0 mac.